# jQuery hot-keys with WordPress next-post

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the hot keys functionality within WordPress to create keyboard navigation within project. Though the keyboard functionality is working, yet for some reason it will only scroll to the next project instead of going to the previous project. When I physically click on the arrows with my mouse everything works just fine, but for some reason when using the keyboard it doesn't work.

Here is the link to a project

http://geoffgeoff.com/dialect-skateboards-identity/

This is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // This uses the Hotkeys jQuery plugin. See below for
    // the native jQuery alternative.
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'left', function() {
        var url = $('#left_arrow a').attr('href');
        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'right', function() {
        var url = $('#right_arrow a').attr('href');
        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't assign the key this way. actually you are binding the two functions to the global-keydown-event, the second function overwrites the first one. try to push any key while visiting your site - every key will load the next article.

the right way is to detect the pressed key inside the function and then trigger the click on the correct anchor-element:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (evnt) {

    var elem = evnt.keyCode === 37 // left arrow
        ? '#left_arrow a'
        : evnt.keyCode === 39 // right arrow
        ? '#right_arrow a'
        : false;

    if ( !elem ) {
        return;
    }

    $(elem).trigger('click');

});
```

if the keyCode is 37, the left arrow was pressed, if the keyCode is 39 the right arrow was pressed. by using the ternary operator, one can assign false to the elem-variable if neither left nor right was clicked. in this case the function returns false and nothing happens.

otherwise, the click-event of the left- or right-anchor gets triggered.